# How to join two parquet datasets?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm loading two DataSets from a Parquet File in Spark with Java. I need to create a new one as a combination of both. In regular SQL I would join the tables, apply some where conditions and create a new tables. Is there any way to realize this in Spark (SQL)? I read that it's possible with RDDs but I don't really want to write back the data to the disk.

Comment: There are typical join operations available in sparkSQL like `join`,`union`. etc..

Comment: what output you want just join two dataset or anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost like something Spark SQL was designed for given parquet is the default format.

Reading a parquet file is a no-brainer and looks like:

```
val fileOne = spark.read.load(...)
val fileTwo = spark.read.load(...)
```

And joining in Spark SQL is a no-brainer, too (and hides whether you deal with parquet datasets or anything else). Use `join` operator.

```
val joined = fileOne.join(fileTwo).where(...)
```

With that, saving to a data store, say as one big(ger) parquet file is again a no-brainer.

```
joined.write.save(...)
```

You're done. Congrats!

Please read up on [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) and [Dataset API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).